# LinkedIn Api error

Tags: c#, desktop-application, linkedin-api

I download the examble "linkedIntollkit" 
I want to get my infor Account and friend list for my destop app.
this is the source.
 http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94877

I tried to run with their APi Key and secret ket (already in code) It run Ok. but when I changed them by mine. I can get 
[image]

after I click "Allow access" I got error
"An eror occured(Access to connetion denied)"
this is my app confi
[image]

[image]

Please tell me what is wrong with my api.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to www.springframework.net/social-linkedin/

Comment: Thank you,bbaia. I tried "ConsoleQuickStart" project. I already got my Information. One more question, Do you know how to get friends'email from LinkedIn.